# Change in Base-Emitter Voltage due to Emitter Degeneration

Tags: bjt, common-emitter, negative-feedback

I am stuck on this circuit from The Art of Electronics, page 117 figure 2.85A.
I have been working on how to derive the equation for the change in Vbe.

[image]

My calculations have been assuming that:
$$ \ i_c \approx i_e $$
Then
$$ \Delta V_c = -i_cR_c = \Delta V_{out} $$
$$ i_c = - \frac{\Delta V_{out} }{Rc}$$

Therefore, for a small change in the base voltage $$\Delta V_{in} = \Delta V_{be} + \Delta V_e $$

$$ \Delta V_{be} = \Delta V_{in} - \Delta V_e $$

$$ \Delta V_{be} = \Delta V_{in} - (\frac{-\Delta V_{out}}{Rc}\times Re) $$

$$ \Delta V_{be} = \Delta V_{in} + \frac{R_e}{R_c} \Delta V_{out}$$

So I've ended up with the addition of the feedback, which doesn't seem quite right. I've looked around at similar websites and found [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/negfeed.html), which seems to have a similar calculation as I do for the change in Vbe.

What am I doing wrong? Is it because the arrow on Vout in the figure is in the opposing direction to Vin?

Comment: You must respect the arrow directions and, if that forces a sign-change then there's the solution.

Comment: During the whole calculation you have used the correct signs......therefore, the last equation must be interpreted correspondingly:  If the Delta-Vout is negative, the increase of the voltage Vbe is smaller than the increase of Vin. And that is correct. However, in the first equation with the minus sign (taken from the book?) the quantity delta-Vout must be regarded as the absolute value (which does not take into consideration the inverting characteristic of the stage)